bash "while read line" loop, with variables as file input
The sample code, and the idea as follows
while read url; do
    wget -q $url -O - | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | grep "magazine/" | grep "https" | sort -u | sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]+).*/\1/g' >> list1
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1 > list
done < list

The initial line of the list is https://abc.xyz/issues/, from here wget wants to find one particular url link to the previous "issue", of the exact format of https://abc.xyz/issues/yyyy/mm/dd (filter by grep, remove duplicates by sort, and extract the url link by sed), then add the url link to the "list", such url link then be used to get the next url link in the "while read line" loop...and the perl line wants to remove duplicates in the list once new url link(s) added to the list, before new url link being processed in the loop.
So this is the idea, and the ideal result should be a list with hundreds of url links for all past issues. Would appreciate some suggestions or better, a simple solution (myself has very basic knowledge of shell command)

I'm not sure what the question is. Does this work or not?

If it doesn't work, what is the expected output and what are you getting instead?

The perl command just seems to be removing duplicates. Didn't you already do that with sort -u?

If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users first.

You should be able to combine all the greps: grep -o -E 'href="https:[^"#]+magazine/[^"#]+"'

@Barmar it doesn't work...running it returns back to prompt immediately, and without any new link in the list...after grep filter, the wget line sometimes still return url links more than just one, and the perl command try to remove such duplicates...thanks for the grep suggestion, I will try it later

@Barmar the command line works, for either wget or perl, if run it in shell; but the loop does not work...the input <list would have a new url link added after each loop, then feed to the wget command to repeat the process, which it does not yet

perl -E 'while($u=shift@ARGV){ push @ARGV, grep{!$seen{$_}++ && say} qx{wget -qO- \Q$u\E} =~ m{href="(https:[^"#]*magazine/[^"#]*)"}g; }' "$url" >list ?

@jhnc this one line command works! it stops at certain link after 150+, and turns out this certain webpage missing the "previous issue" href link...I have little idea how this one line command works, and I'd like to understand the structure if you feel like to comment:)

@jhnc when reuse the above command from the "stop" link, I can manually feed the missing url link, then is it possible for it to follow the existing 'direction' and only get the "previous issue" link, but not the ones already in the list? i.e. /yyyy/mm/dd in the previous links always older than the current link

actually I'm not sure my code does the right thing, since magazine/ does not appear in the url format that you give (https://abc.xyz/issues/yyyy/mm/dd) so it seems you are looking for it somewhere other than the href value. You need to provide sample html from wget.

Shouldn't it be wget -q "$url" ...` ?  Also, it's a good idea to copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any flagged problems. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as your first line of scripting.

@jhnc sorry for that, the website my sample examines is the new yorker "https://www.newyorker.com/magazine", their weekly issues actually follow strict +7 date format in /yyyy/mm/dd from 1925

Here is another approach using bash coproc that may be slightly easier to follow than the Perl.
walk_queue2 :
#!/bin/bash

start_url=$1
seen_urls_file=$2

# (re)load lookup table from previous results found
declare -A seen
if [[ -f $seen_urls_file ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r url; do
        seen["$url"]=1
    done < "$seen_urls_file"
fi
 
# feed in url, get back zero or more urls from its content
# then append "---" to let us track queue length
coproc extract_urls {
    while IFS= read -r url; do
        wget -qO- "$url" |
        grep -oE 'href="https://[^"#]+"' |
        cut -d'"' -f2 |
        grep 'magazine/'

        echo ---
    done
}

queue_length=0
url=$start_url

while
    if (( !seen["$url"]++ )); then
        (( ++queue_length ))
        echo "$url" >& ${extract_urls[1]}
        echo "$url" >> "$seen_urls_file"
        echo "$url"
    fi
    IFS= read -r url
do
    while [[ $url = --- ]]; do
        (( --queue_length == 0 )) && break 2
        IFS= read -r url || break 2
    done
done <& ${extract_urls[0]}

Use as:
$ cat /dev/null >found
$ ./walk_queue2 'https://abc.xyz/start' found
$ ./walk_queue2 'https://abc.xyz/another/one' found


Addendum: As usual, coproc is not needed:
walk_queue3 (same usage as above):
#!/bin/bash

start_url=$1
seen_urls_file=$2

declare -a queue
qpos=0
queue[qpos]=$start_url

declare -A seen
if [[ -f $seen_urls_file ]]; then
    while IFS= read -r url; do
        seen["$url"]=1
    done < "$seen_urls_file"
fi

while (( ${#queue[@]} > qpos )); do

    # for simplicity, we don't delete from queue
    url=${queue[qpos++]}

    while IFS= read -r new_url; do
        if (( !seen["$new_url"]++ )); then
            queue+=("$new_url")
            echo "$new_url" >> "$seen_urls_file"
            echo "$new_url"
        fi
    done < <(
        wget -qO- "$url" |
        grep -oE 'href="https://[^"#]+"' |
        cut -d'"' -f2 |
        grep 'magazine/'
    )
done

Note that slowness will probably be due to throttling by the website owner who may object to their website being scraped.

The extra meal is delicious too!

With:
while read url; do
    ...
    perl ... list1 > list
done < list

You're writing to the same file you're reading, list, don't do that. Change
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1 > list
done < list

to
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1 > outfile
done < list

or better:
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1
done < list > outfile

to avoid THAT major problem but then you also have more problems including this:
wget ... >> list1
perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1

which is constantly appending to list1 so perl has to re-process previous contents again on every loop iteration. You should probably be doing:
wget ... > list1
perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' list1

to repopulate list1 on every iteration instead of appending to it, instead but idk why you're even using a file there instead of just piping to perl:
wget ... |
perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;'

Overall, this might be what you're trying to do (untested and not recommending the approach, just trying to make the OPs code function):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r url; do
    wget -q "$url" -O - |
    grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' |
    grep "magazine/" |
    grep "https" |
    sort -u |
    sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]+).*/\1/g' |
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' 
done < list > outfile

Without sample input (output from curl) and expected output (from the loop) this is all just guesswork but the above then could probably be changed to this so as to not spawn subshells repeatedly to call all of those commands inside the loop:
while IFS= read -r url; do
    wget -q "$url" -O -
done < list |
    grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' |
    grep "magazine/" |
    grep "https" |
    sort -u |
    sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]+).*/\1/g' |
    perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' \
        > outfile

and I further expect that this pipeline of 6 commands:
grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' |
grep "magazine/" |
grep "https" |
sort -u |
sed -r 's/.*href="([^"]+).*/\1/g' |
perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' 

could be replaced with a single awk (or perl) command.

Great! this is really something I need to feed myself:) falling into this bash rabbit hole recently...in my sample code, when I run wget line followed by perl line, and get the new url link, I manually copy it to $url and repeat the process, and I can get the url links I expect, but don't know how to pass the new url the "bash way" :) this helps a lot!

It seems you want a FIFO (first-in, first-out) data structure, aka queue.
You can probably replace all your code with a single Perl script.
A slightly-easier to read version of the code from my comment, using intermediate variables, and altered to allow resuming from a new queue:
walk_queue :
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my ($url_queue_file, $seen_urls_file) = @ARGV;

# allow reading/writing file lines as if they are arrays  
tie my @url_queue, 'Tie::File', $url_queue_file or die;
tie my @seen_urls, 'Tie::File', $seen_urls_file or die;

# (re)load lookup table from any previous results found
my %seen = map {$_=>1} @seen_urls;

# take url from head of queue
while (my $url = shift @url_queue) {
 
    # call wget - quote any metacharacters in url
    my $html = qx{ wget -qO- \Q$url\E };

    # extract href values that are https urls
    my @found_urls = ( $html =~ m{href="(https://[^"#]+)"}g );

    # filter out irrelevant and duplicates
    my @new_urls = grep { m{magazine/} && !$seen{$_}++ } @found_urls;

    # add any new urls to tail of queue
    push @url_queue, @new_urls;

    # ensure starting url is always marked as seen 
    unshift @new_urls, $url if !$seen{$url}++;

    # append any new urls to result file
    push @seen_urls, @new_urls;

    # optionally output progress to screen
    say for @new_urls;
}

then:
$ echo 'https://abc.xyz/start' >queue
$ cat /dev/null >found
$ ./walk_queue queue found


queue should end up empty
found should contain the results (also displayed on stdout)

To continue from a different url, add it to queue but don't clear found, and run again:
$ echo 'https://abc.xyz/another/one' >>queue
$ ./walk_queue queue found

(I haven't tested this code since I don't know the actual url format nor html contents.)

Thank you so much! I will have to digest the code for a while, perl is literally a word I searched and brew-installed a few days ago, with a command copied/pasted from this forum when I searched for answers:)...curious about the one-line command you suggested previously, run it a dozen of times, each time feed with a new url link, it exits randomly each time, from the result list, every time it will follow "previous/next" url links both ways from the start, for the first couple hundred links, then it will "decide" to go just one direction to the end after that, wondering how it "decide"?

probably because links are more likely to be duplicates as it runs longer - the comment code doesn't resume; it always starts with an empty "seen" hash. output should be deterministic for any specific starting url

The code works without any change!... first run exits after 17m28s on my m1 studio, with 330 links in found, and at its 2nd run now

note that scraping a website can be frowned on by its owner. and while possibly not an issue here, in general performing rate-limiting is considered polite even when scraping is tolerated

agreed...nothing more than interest, content and code
